# How to get OAuth Token Secret

Tags: webservices, oauth2

OAuth authentication depends on the permissions granted within the OAuth consumer token. I am clear with this, but how can I get the "OAuth **token secret**" apart from OAuth token?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of oauth2 when you create application on site to which you are integrating, provides two compulsory values

- consumer secret
- token secret

here "oauth token secret" is "token secret".

We never need to get it throug any api callout. It is stored in oauth application setting.

It is normally hardcoded in post request we made to request access token to work on behalf of user.
So you don't need to get you just need copy from application setting.

This a generic answer as you have not provided details about site to which you are integrating.